# <li> on click to Populate an Input with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am populating a `<ul>` with ajax using values from an input box and need to get the value (and id) from the `<li>` element to that same input box on click. I am trying to create an autocomplete type of input. What I have so far is working with static `li` elements but with `li` elements appended with JQuery, the input box is not getting any values from the `<li>`.

**View**

```
          <input type="text" name="vendor_id" id="search_vendor">

          <ul id="vendor_list"></ul>
```

**Script**

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#search_vendor").keyup(function(e) {

                if($(this).val().length > 0){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/search_vendor_ajax",
                        data: { search_vendor: $(this).val() },
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function(data){
                            $(data).each(function(i, value){
                                $('#vendor_list').append(
                                    $('<li>')
                                        .append(value.vendor_name)
                                        .attr('id', value.id)
                                        .attr('class','vendor_li')
                                );
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            // Select Vendor
            $('li.vendor_li').on('click',function(){
                var content= $(this).text();
                $('#search_vendor').val(content);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: li is dynamic, so using $('li.vendor_li') may not work.
trying to add document like. For eg:
$(document).on("click","#test-element",function() {});

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: `$("#search_vendor").keyup(function(e) {` don't use "keyup" use the "input" eventname instead: `$("#search_vendor").on("input", function(e) {` - such will cover all the cases, even copy/pasting a value into the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `li` items are not available on the `ready` event because you are populating them with AJAX, so the `onclick` event listener cannot be added on the `ready` event.

You have to change the event listener to attach it to the `ul` and target the click on every `li`, no matter when it's added. This is called [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$('#vendor_list').on('click', 'li.vendor_li', function(){
    const content= $(this).text();
    $('#search_vendor').val(content);
});
```